# magento sub theme possible?

Tags: magento, themes

i'm creating a magento shop.
I've downloaded a new Template.
The template has an own "package" folder and has its phtml files in the "default" folder inside the package.

Now i begun to add a theme folder in this package to customize the downloaded template. 
Everything is working fine.

But now i want to create sub-designs for this customized version, to make some shop-categories look different (I can change the theme for single categories in the backend).

is it possible?
what can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Aoe_DesignFallback extension will help you http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/custom-design-fallbacks-in-magento.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create as many theme variations as you want inside your custom package

package/default
package/theme1
package/theme2
...
package/themeN

Inside these themes you can customize as many files as you want. For example, you can edit only one specific template for on specific theme. Because of Magento fall-back mechanism all the rest files will be used from 'default' theme of your package and then from 'default' theme of 'base' package

Read this guide:
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

Comment: hi yes i know, but i need that theme2 is derived from theme1

Comment: why can't you copy theme1 in theme2 and change what should be changed there?

Comment: that would be possible, but when i change theme1 i had to change all other themes too

Comment: unfortunately it's not like in Wordpress when you can specify which theme would be a parent one for each child theme. So you need either do it this way or make your theme1 default theme in your custom package.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make different designs for different categories, and at the backend,

```
Catalog > Manage Categories > for each categories > Custom Design Tab
```

You can select the design you want for that particular category.

You can also add something in Custom Layout Update as per your need.

You can even give time range that design will be shown and automatically display the default design after that time.

Comment: hi i know that, my problem is that i want to create sub-themes which i can choose for these categories

Answer (score 0):

The only fallback mechanism for themes in Magento is between the supplied 'base' theme and your selected theme. That is, Magento will look for files in your selected theme, and, if any specific file is not found, will fallback to the supplied 'base' theme.

So, you can probably merge your desired theme with the 'base' theme, and replace the 'base' theme with this newly-created theme. Then, you can create one single sub-theme that can fallback on the new 'base' theme. I will not recommend you doing this, as this will make upgrading to new versions of Magento very difficult.

If you really want to make this work, I will recommend having a workflow outside of Magento to handle your files in the themes and sub-themes. Perhaps some sort of scripts that take files from the main theme and merge them into the sub-themes before copying all the themes and sub-themes folders into Magento.